# How to have a random selection reference a previous random selection for an RPG lifepath generator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, random

I'm trying to make a Javascript version of a basic "life path generator" often found in pen and paper RPGs. I've made generators based on the template found here: http://donjon.bin.sh/code/random/

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to make a reference to a previously selected random outcome.

The pen and paper equivalent might look something like this: Roll d6 to determine class (Bard, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Rogue, Wizard). Roll a d20 to determine a background for character (with each background being unique to its class).

I'm guessing I'll make arrays or objects for each set, but I don't know how to make the second set trigger off the first random selection automatically. I'd like to have it set where I can press one button and have everything generated randomly.

Here is as close as I can figure out:

```
  var gen_data = {};
  gen_data['main'] = {
    'You are a {class}.' 
  if {class} = Bard '{bardBackstory}'
  else if {class} = Cleric '{clericBackstory}'
  else if {class} = Druid '{druidBackstory}'
  else if {class} = Fighter '{fighterBackstory}'
  else if {class} = Rogue '{rogueBackstory}'
  else if {class} = Wizard 'wizardBackstory}'
  };
  gen_data['class'] = {
    '1': 'Bard',
    '2': 'Cleric',
    '3': 'Druid',
    '4': 'Fighter',
    '5': 'Rogue',
    '6': 'Wizard
  };
  gen_data['bardBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
  gen_data['clericBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
  gen_data['druidBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
  gen_data['fighterBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
  gen_data['rogueBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
  gen_data['wizardBackstory'] = {
    '1': 'story1',
    '2': 'story2',
    '3': 'etc'
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript in generator.js (the base/64 code in random.html) uses RegEx to search strings for words inside `'{example_here}'` and replaces them with the value of a random member of the object held at `gen_data['example_here']`. Subsequent uses of `{}` will create the nesting effect that you desire.

```
var gen_data = {};
gen_data['main'] = ['You are a {class}.']
gen_data['class'] = {
  '1': 'Bard. {bardBackstory}',
  '2': 'Fighter. {fighterBackstory}',
  '3': 'Wizard. {wizardBackstory}'
};
gen_data['bardBackstory'] = {
  '1': 'story1',
  '2': 'story2',
  '3': 'etc'
};
gen_data['fighterBackstory'] = {
  '1': 'story1',
  '2': 'story2',
  '3': 'etc'
};
gen_data['wizardBackstory'] = {
  '1': 'story1',
  '2': 'story2',
  '3': 'etc'
};
```

Comment: When I tested this out, it wouldn't produce any output. I'm guessing something about the nesting is preventing it from executing, but not sure what.

Comment: I fixed an error in the example above. `gen_data['main']` should be an array of length 1 instead of an object. Change `gen_data['main'] = {'You are a {class}'}` to `gen_data['main'] = ['You are a {class}']`.